# Creating Generic Delegates with Generic Interface Arguments

Tags: c#, generics, interface, delegates

I want to create a generic delegate. It will delegate functions that have generic types as parameter.

For example : 
I have an interface :

```
public interface IProblemState<T> : IComparable<IProblemState<T>>, IEquatable<IProblemState<T>>
        where T : IEquatable<T>
{}
```

And I have two different class

```
public class Class1 : IEquatable<Class1>
{ }

public class Class2 : **IProblemState<Class1>**
{ }
```

And after I have an delegate

```
public delegate SortedSet<IProblemState<T>> ExpanderDelegate<T>(IProblemState<T> currentState) 
        where T : IEquatable<T>;
```

I can NOT create a delegate with a function that have derived class parameter (Instance of Class 2).

For Example :

```
SortedSet<**Class2**> expander(**Class2** currentState)
{}

ExpanderDelegate<Class2> expanderDel = new ExpanderDelegate(**expander**);
```

When I want to create delegate, I get below error.

> *No overload for 'expander' matches delegate 'ExpanderDelegate'*

I want to use this delegate with all function that have derived parameters.

Is it possible with C#?

Thanks.

Comment: Wow the classes are very complicated can you simplify the problem more please. I think your problem is related to Covariance and Contravariance in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you cannot. The delegate says: give me a function that can take *any* `IProblemState<T>` as a parmeter, and you give it a function that can *only* take `Class2`.

What if there were a `Class3` that also implements `IProblemState<T>`? Surely, the delegate signature says I should be able to pass an instance of `Class3` in as a parameter. But the function wouldn't allow it (it only allows `Class2` instances). That's why that function cannot be assigned to a variable of that delegate type.

What you can do, is use this generic delegate:

```
public delegate SortedSet<T> ExpanderDelegate<T,U>(T currentState) 
    where T : IProblemState<U> where U: IEquatable<U>;
```